# Stress-energy tensor of Jordan-Fierz-Brans-Dicke action

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, metric-tensor, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, variational-calculus

I have a question about the JFBD action, in particular the part that involves a scalar field. It is given by $$ S_\phi = \int d^4x \sqrt{-g} \left( \frac{1}{2} g^{\mu\nu}(\nabla_{
\mu}\phi)(\nabla_{\nu}\phi)-V(\phi)-\frac{\xi}{2}R\phi^2 \right).$$
The energy-stress tensor is defined as $T_{\mu\nu}^{\phi}:=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{-g}}\frac{\delta S_{\phi}}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}$. I should get the following:
$$T_{\mu\nu}^{\phi}=(\partial_{\mu}\phi)(\partial_{\nu}\phi)-g_{\mu\nu}\left[\frac{1}{2}g^{\alpha\beta}(\partial_{\alpha}\phi)(\partial_{\beta}\phi)-V(\phi) \right] -\xi G_{\mu\nu}\phi^2-\xi[\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}-g_{\mu\nu}\square]\phi^2,$$
where $G_{\mu\nu}=R_{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R$, $\square=g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}$ and $R$ the Ricci scalar. Now the terms up and including to the one containing the Einstein tensor I can figure out, but then I get into trouble. I used that $ \delta R=R_{\mu\nu} \delta g^{\mu\nu} + \nabla_{\rho}(g^{\mu\nu}\delta \Gamma^{\rho}_{\mu\nu}-g^{\mu\rho} \delta \Gamma_{\nu\mu}^{\nu})$ and here the second term does not vanish by stokes because it is coupled to the field $\phi$ which depends on spacetime. But I am not sure how to treat it and prove that $\nabla_{\rho}(g^{\mu\nu}\delta \Gamma^{\rho}_{\mu\nu}-g^{\mu\rho} \delta \Gamma_{\nu\mu}^{\nu})=[\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}-g_{\mu\nu}\square]\delta g^{\mu\nu}$ or something else in this direction. Any hints or solutions would be very welcome.

Comment: How did you obtain last term in stress-energy tensor?

Comment: You can mention that last term in the action looks like gravity action times $\phi^2$, so it gives us only Einstein tensor. Did I missing something?

Comment: The last term is the action is the nonminimal coupling, and the fact that it is multiplied by $\phi^2$ makes it different because $\phi=\phi(x)$ a field that depends on spacetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using (see for example [What's the variation of the Christoffel symbols with respect to the metric?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/462686/whats-the-variation-of-the-christoffel-symbols-with-respect-to-the-metric))

$$
\delta\Gamma^\sigma_{\mu\nu}=\frac{1}{2}g^{\sigma\lambda}(\nabla_\nu\delta g_{\mu\lambda}+\nabla_\mu\delta g_{\nu\lambda}-\nabla_\lambda\delta g_{\mu\nu}).
$$

One can check, that:
$$
\nabla_{\rho}(g^{\mu\nu}\delta \Gamma^{\rho}_{\mu\nu}-g^{\mu\rho} \delta \Gamma_{\nu\mu}^{\nu})=[\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}-g_{\mu\nu}\square]\delta g^{\mu\nu}
$$

So integrating by parts you obtain last term..