# GR Lagrangian with higher-order curvature terms

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, curvature, variational-principle, variational-calculus

I'm trying to find papers / books / lectures with the derivation of the equations of motion from Lagrangians with higher order in curvature terms, for example with the Kretschmann scalar $R_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}R^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}$ or the Chern-Pontryagin scalar $^\star R_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}R^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}$.
I want to figure out how the Einstein equations changes if we use the Lagrangian $\int R_{\mu \nu \rho \sigma}R^{\mu \nu \rho \sigma} \sqrt{-g}d^4 x$.

Comment: [This page](http://www.phy.olemiss.edu/~luca/Topics/grav/higherorder.html) and the references therein may be helpful.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein–Hilbert_action#Variation_of_the_Riemann_tensor,_the_Ricci_tensor,_and_the_Ricci_scalar) explains how to vary the Riemann tensor. From this you should be able to calculate the field equations for any Lagrangian constructed from this tensor.

Comment: You also need the variation of the Christoffel symbols, which is discussed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/462686/whats-the-variation-of-the-christoffel-symbols-with-respect-to-the-metric).

Comment: It might be hard to find explicit derivations. If you just want the final EOM, I would suggest you learn xAct and get your answer in 2 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are familiar with [the variation  of the Einstein-Hilbert (EH) action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action). Assuming this, from variation of the EH action, we learn the following rules
$$\delta \sqrt { - g}  =  - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt { - g} {g_{\mu \nu }}\delta {g^{\mu \nu }},$$
and
$$\delta \left( {{R^a}_{bcd}} \right) = {\nabla _c}\left( {\delta \Gamma _{db}^a} \right) - {\nabla _d}\left( {\delta \Gamma _{cb}^a} \right),$$
where
$$ \delta\Gamma^a_{b c}=\frac{1}{2}g^{a\lambda}(\nabla_c\delta g_{b\lambda}+\nabla_b\delta g_{c \lambda}-\nabla_\lambda\delta g_{b c}), $$
and also
$$\delta {g^{\mu \nu }} =  - {g^{\mu \alpha }}{g^{\beta \nu }}(\delta {g_{\alpha \beta }}),$$
which are important ingredients in  what follows.

Now, let's consider your case, i.e., $\int {{d^4}x\sqrt { - g} {R_{abcd}}{R^{abcd}}}$. To do so, you need to rewrite the Kretschmann scalar as
$${R_{abcd}}{R^{abcd}} = {g^{bx}}{g^{cy}}{g^{dz}}{g_{am}}{R^a}_{bcd}{R^m}_{xyz}.$$

Finally, you can simply obtain the following result
$$\delta \left( {\sqrt { - g} {R_{abcd}}{R^{abcd}}} \right) = \delta \left( {\sqrt { - g} {g^{bx}}{g^{cy}}{g^{dz}}{g_{am}}{R^a}_{bcd}{R^m}_{xyz}} \right).$$

Straightforwardly, by use of the first four relations in this answer, you can read the resulting field equation of motion. For a full discussion about these kinds of Lagrangians, please [see this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.2739). I highly recommend reading  Sect. **4.3** of [Spacetime and Geometry by Carroll](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0805387323), which gives you anything you need to deal with Lagrangian formalism and variational principle. Hopefully this helps.